# can not autoconf for cgminer (missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS)

Tags: c, linux, autoconf, automake

I try to build cgminer for server from the source-code

since it make by autoconfig and automake, I use autoscan try to scan it.
but the problem is: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS and other missing, what the source file or library I missed?

may command in shell is:

```
root@localhost:~/cgminer-3.4.2/cgminer# autoscan
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([clock_gettime]) wanted by: util.c
:981
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([dup2]) wanted by: cgminer.c:7270
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([floor]) wanted by: cgminer.c:2167
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gethostbyname]) wanted by: api-ex
ample.c:201
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gettimeofday]) wanted by: util.c:
974
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([inet_ntoa]) wanted by: api.c:4331
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([localeconv]) wanted by: compat/ja
nsson/strconv.c:26
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memchr]) wanted by: util.c:174
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memmove]) wanted by: util.c:1344
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset]) wanted by: api-example.c
:209
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([mkdir]) wanted by: cgminer.c:4788
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([select]) wanted by: util.c:1163
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([setenv]) wanted by: ccan/opt/test
/run.c:284
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([socket]) wanted by: api-example.c
:203
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strcasecmp]) wanted by: util.c:20
1
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strchr]) wanted by: api-example.c
:153
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strcspn]) wanted by: ccan/opt/opt
.c:29
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strdup]) wanted by: util.c:490
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strerror]) wanted by: libztex.c:2
24
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strncasecmp]) wanted by: adl.c:12
61
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strrchr]) wanted by: driver-modmi
ner.c:397
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strspn]) wanted by: ccan/opt/test
/run-helpers.c:339
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strstr]) wanted by: util.c:1096
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strtol]) wanted by: cgminer.c:892
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([arpa/inet.h]) wanted by: api-ex
ample.c:32
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h]) wanted by: util.c:27
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([float.h]) wanted by: driver-bfl
sc.c:11
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([limits.h]) wanted by: ocl.c:17
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([locale.h]) wanted by: compat/ja
nsson/strconv.c:9
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([mach/mach.h]) wanted by: util.c
:1016
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([malloc.h]) wanted by: miner.h:6
0
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([netdb.h]) wanted by: api-exampl
e.c:33
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([netinet/in.h]) wanted by: api-e
xample.c:31
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stddef.h]) wanted by: uthash.h:
28
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([sys/ioctl.h]) wanted by: fpgaut
ils.c:23
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([sys/socket.h]) wanted by: api-e
xample.c:30
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([sys/time.h]) wanted by: compat.
h:9
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([termios.h]) wanted by: fpgautil
s.c:22
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADERS([wchar.h]) wanted by: lib/string
.in.h:37
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_HEADER_STDBOOL wanted by: ocl.h:28
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_CHECK_TYPES([ptrdiff_t]) wanted by: uthash.h:7
79
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_C_INLINE wanted by: compat.h:17
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_C_RESTRICT wanted by: lib/sigaction.c:131
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_FUNC_FORK wanted by: cgminer.c:7290
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_FUNC_MALLOC wanted by: libztex.c:230
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_FUNC_REALLOC wanted by: util.c:132
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_FUNC_STRTOD wanted by: driver-bitforce.c:401
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_INT16_T wanted by: libztex.h:49
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_INT32_T wanted by: compat/jansson/dump.c:
68
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_INT64_T wanted by: driver-bitfury.c:196
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_PID_T wanted by: lib/signal.in.h:305
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_SSIZE_T wanted by: fpgautils.h:30
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_UID_T wanted by: lib/signal.in.h:306
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_UINT16_T wanted by: libztex.c:76
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_UINT32_T wanted by: findnonce.h:16
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_UINT64_T wanted by: usbutils.h:217
configure.ac: warning: missing AC_TYPE_UINT8_T wanted by: libztex.c:105
```

Answer (score 2):

Autoscan is only when you're creating a new package from scratch. Use

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything.  `autoscan` is not something you should be running unless you are the package maintainer, and it is overly verbose about checking for functions.  These warnings are simply telling you that the configure script will not be checking for the named functions, headers, or variable types but a cursory scan of the list does not give rise to any real concerns.  The maintainers have constructed a `configure.ac` that appears to assume the user is using a relatively modern system and a C compiler that recognizes the `restrict` keyword.  Personally, if I were maintaining the package, I would add the checks for `AC_C_RESTRICT` and `AC_C_INLINE` and probably a few others, but as a user you can safely ignore these warnings.  If you are just trying to build the package, don't run the autotool chain; just get a source package that has already built the necessary files and build it from that.